# tweepy's get_users_tweets: URLs are not included in the "entities" dictionary returned for a ReplyTweet

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I'm iterating over `response = tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets, id=..., tweet_fields="created_at,in_reply_to_user_id,public_metrics,entities",` and for normal normal tweets the corresponding object inside `response.data` has the tweet URLs in `["entities"]["urls"]` field but it seems that for tweets that are Replies the URLs are not there. Is this normal? How can I get URLs for tweet replies?